# Mark a row in a data table as deleted

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

How do I mark a row from my data table deleted and still keep it there for restoration purposes?

I'm trying to temporarily delete a record from a parent table that has 3 child tables. Which means If I delete a record from table A, the records that are dependent on the temporarily deleted record should not be visible on the data table as well.

So far, I've used an `ON DELETE CASCADE` for it but it deletes all the records permanently.

What should I do?

Comment: Are you talking about .NET `DataTable` class and relations in a `DataSet` or are you talking about sql-server only? Can you show some code and the schema of your tables?

Comment: One way to *soft-delete* is to have a `is_deleted` flag or a `deleted_at` date column.

Comment: @TimSchmelter .NET DataTable yes. I just need to disable deleted row (or as ive said mark it as deleted) but it is still in the database because I have a restore function.

My parent table which is COMPANY table has  DEPARTMENT table dependent to it and DEPARTMENT table has POSITION table dependent to it.

Comment: Hi @FelixPamittan can u pls elaborate on that further. Thanks! xx

Comment: So you want that if you delete a `DataRow` in a `DataTable` all through foreign-keys referenced `DataRows` in related tables are also deleted, so their `DataRowState` changes to `Deleted`? That's default if you define relations.

Comment: @TimSchmelter  that's exactly what I wanna do

Comment: @Kylie: but as far as i know that is default, so happens automatically if you properly define [foreign key constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st1t2c35(v=vs.110).aspx). You have to use `RejectChanges` if you want to undo those deletes. Also remember to set `foreignKeyConstraint.AcceptRejectRule = AcceptRejectRule.Cascade` which isn't default.